# How to convert php or xml to Node?

Tags: php, node.js, xml, wsdl

I am using the following php to send SMS, which is in php. So I am unable to add with Node Js project. So I need to change to Node. But there is web service for web service users [here](http://smeapps.mobitel.lk:8585/EnterpriseSMSV2/EnterpriseSMSWS.wsdl). When I tried the link in SoapUI, it works fine and send SMS. When I tried the code in Node Js, I did not get Sesson Id and not send SMS.

**What I tried in Node**

```
router.post("/register", upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next)
{
  var url = 'http://smeapps.mobitel.lk:8585/EnterpriseSMSV2/EnterpriseSMSWS?wsdl';

  var session = {username: 'myUserName', password: 'myPassword'} 

  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client)
  {
    if(err)
    console.log(err)
    client.createSession(session, function(err, result)
    {
      console.log('The result is : ' + result);
    });

    var smsMessage = {message:'Sample', recipient:'9471xxxxxxx'}
    client.sendMessages(smsMessage, function(err, result2)
    {
      console.log("Send Msg err : " + err);
      console.log('The result is : ' + result2);
    });
  })
})
```

**Console output is**

```
The result is : [object Object]
Send Msg err : Error: SOAP-ENV:Server: Procedure 'sendMessages' not present
The result is : [object Object]
```

**php code**

```
<?php
    require_once('ESMSWS.php');

    $username = 'username'; 
    $password = 'password'; 
    $recipient = 9471xxxxxxx; 
    $alias = 'App Name'; 
    $message_body = "Sample";

    $session = createSession('',$username,$password,'');
    var_dump($session); 

    $sndMsg = sendMessages($session,$alias,$message_body,$recipient);
    var_dump($sndMsg); 

    //closeSession($session);
?>
```

**Success php output**

```
C:\wamp64\www\sms\esmsclientapp.php:11:
object(stdClass)[6]
  public 'expiryDate' => string '2018-10-04T06:40:07+05:30' (length=25)
  public 'isActive' => boolean true
  public 'sessionId' => string '775858578314' (length=12)
  public 'user' => int 0
C:\wamp64\www\sms\esmsclientapp.php:16:int 200  // 200 means message sent
```

**SoapUI create session**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.esms.mobitel.lk/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:createSession>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <customer>12</customer>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <id>12</id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <password>password</password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <username>username</username>
         </arg0>
      </ws:createSession>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Success SoapUI session output**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.esms.mobitel.lk/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:createSessionResponse>
         <return>
            <expiryDate>2018-10-04T06:24:25+05:30</expiryDate>
            <isActive>true</isActive>
            <sessionId>761033662786</sessionId>
            <user>0</user>
         </return>
      </ns1:createSessionResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**SoapUI send Message**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.esms.mobitel.lk/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:sendMessages>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <expiryDate>2018-10-04T05:12:26+05:30</expiryDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <id>1</id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <isActive>1</isActive>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <sessionId>761033662786</sessionId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <user>1</user>
         </arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <message>Sample</message>
            <messageId>1</messageId>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <recipients>9471xxxxxxx</recipients>
            <retries>0</retries>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <sender>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <alias>App Name</alias>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <customer>1</customer>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <id>1</id>
            </sender>
            <sequenceNum>1</sequenceNum>
            <status>1</status>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <time>2018-10-04T05:12:26+05:30</time>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <type>?</type>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <user>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <customer>1</customer>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <id>1</id>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <password>password</password>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <username>username</username>
            </user>
         </arg1>
      </ws:sendMessages>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Success SoapUI sentmessage output**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.esms.mobitel.lk/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:sendMessagesResponse>
         <return>200</return>
      </ns1:sendMessagesResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'd suggest moving your node code block to the top. Since the question seems to be more about how to get that code working people will be most interested in it, and it may also prevent people from mistakenly downvoting your question because they haven't read the whole thing and think that you haven't tried anything.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the Node code above